# Drawing a triangle with rounded bottom in CSS?

Tags: css, geometry, draw

In css I can draw a triangle as following:

[image: triangle]

```
.triangle{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 200px 200px 0;
    border-color: transparent #48a665 transparent transparent;
}

<div class="triangle"></div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cn8K/)

Now I want to draw a triangle with rounded at bottom like this:

[image: border-radius]

Is it possible to make it with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we create a circle and place it on top to make it look like how you want it, you get something like this:

### CSS:

```
.triangle{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 200px 200px 0;
    border-color: transparent #48a665 transparent transparent;
}
.triangle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 200px;
    left: -190px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

You need to set the background color (currently `#fff` ) to match the background it is placed on.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cn8K/7/)

Answer (score 3):

On the assumption of a solid background area for the concave section, you can use:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/x4wLf/340/)

CSS

```
div {
    background:red;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:200%;
    width:200%;
    left:-100%;
    background:white; /* <-- change as appropriate */
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

This simply overlays an offset circle onto the element, positioned to cover up a section of it to leave the appearance of the element being concave.

Comment: Ah what, you get a `+1` and are answers are pretty much the same! haha, `+1` from me anyways. Good job.

Comment: @Ruddy - luck of the draw, think I was marginally faster- if its all the same, I missed out consistently yesterday to people who posted the same after me, or edited their answers to include mine, c'est la vie mon ami :(